# ImagePulloff error while deploying on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Hey there so I was trying to deploy my first and simple webapp with no database on minikube but this Imagepulloff error keeps coming in the pod.
Yes I have checked the name of Image,tag several times;
Here are the logs and yml files.

```
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Labels:           app=nodeapp1
                pod-template-hash=589c6bd468        
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Pending
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nodeapp1-deployment-589c6bd468
Containers:
nodeserver:
  Container ID:
  Image:          ayushftw/nodeapp1:latest
  Image ID:
  Port:           3000/TCP
  Host Port:      0/TCP
  State:          Waiting
    Reason:       ErrImagePull
  Ready:          False
  Restart Count:  0
  Environment:    <none>
  Mounts:
    /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-k6mkb (ro)
Conditions:
Type              Status
Initialized       True
Ready             False
ContainersReady   False
PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
kube-api-access-k6mkb:
  Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
  TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
  ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
  DownwardAPI:             true
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
Type     Reason     Age   From               Message
----     ------     ----  ----               -------
Normal   Scheduled  2m3s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nodeapp1-deployment-589c6bd468-5lg2n to minikube
Normal   Pulling    2m2s  kubelet            Pulling image "ayushftw/nodeapp1:latest"
Warning  Failed     3s    kubelet            Failed to pull image "ayushftw/nodeapp1:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded
Warning  Failed     3s    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
Normal   BackOff    2s    kubelet            Back-off pulling image "ayushftw/nodeapp1:latest"
Warning  Failed     2s    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

deployment.yml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment

metadata:

  name: nodeapp1-deployment

  labels:

    app: nodeapp1

spec:

  replicas: 1

  selector:

    matchLabels:

      app: nodeapp1

  template:

    metadata:

      labels:

        app: nodeapp1

    spec:

      containers:

      - name: nodeserver

        image: ayushftw/nodeapp1:latest

        ports:

        - containerPort: 3000
```

service.yml fie

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodeapp1-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nodeapp1
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 31011
```

Please Help If anybody knows anything about this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your internet connection is slow. The timeout to pull an image is `120` seconds, so kubectl could not pull the image in under `120` seconds.

First, pull the image via `Docker`

```bash
docker image pull ayushftw/nodeapp1:latest
```

Then load the downloaded image to `minikube`

```bash
minikube image load ayushftw/nodeapp1:latest
```

And then everything will work because now kubectl will use the image that is stored locally.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the ability to reach container registry or registry in use for your images. Can you try to pull the image manually from the node?